# How does blender calculate the catmull-clark subdivision mesh including edge creases?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, geometry

A basic description of the catmull-clark subdivision algorithm can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull-clark) and on this [page](http://w3.impa.br/~lcruz/courses/cma/surfaces.html) (it seems that blender does not differentiate between corner and side case - tested with this [python script](http://www.pasteall.org/52844/python)) .

How does blender calculate the catmull-clark subdivision mesh including edge creases?